# Is $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$ locally compact?

Tags: general-topology

So I believe the answer is no, because the answer is no for rationals. I feel that every word in the proof of rationals not being locally compact can be changed to irrationals. But I wasn't totally confident since I am a beginner student of topology.

Comment: What proof have you for $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: In fact if $D$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ such that $\Bbb R\setminus D$ is also dense, then $D$ is not locally compact. This fact applies to $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb P$.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, $\Bbb P$ (the irrationals) are a non-locally compact space, and the proof *can* be similar to a proof as given for $\Bbb Q$ (but for the latter we can also say it's not Baire so cannot be locally compact, but $\Bbb P$ is actually Baire so that particular argument does not translate).

You can use that irrational sequences can converge to rational points, e.g.